# Scala how to return constant

Tags: scala, function, constants

I'm working on some practice problems and super confused how to return "constants"

```
//Complete the following definition, so that "constant5" is a function that returns 5
// whenever it is invoked.
val constant5 : () => Int = {

}

//Complete the following definition, so that "constant" is a function that when
// invoked with integer n returns a function that returns n whenever it is invoked.
val constant : Int => () => Int = {

}
```

Here's examples of how they'll be called

```
assert ({ 
  val r1 : Int = constant5 ()
  val r2 : Int = constant5 ()
  (r1, r2)
} === (5, 5)
)

assert ({ 
  val k1 : () => Int = constant (1)
  val k2 : () => Int = constant (2)
  val r1 : Int = k1 ()
  val r2 : Int = k1 ()
  val r3 : Int = k2 ()
  val r4 : Int = k2 ()
  val r5 : Int = k2 ()
  val r6 : Int = k1 ()
  (r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6)
} === (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
)
```

I have absolutely no clue where to start with these. 
I thought new Int(5) would solve the first one but you can't instantiate Int class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number itself is a constant. The first part of the method signature's return type shows you `() => Int`, which means a function, given no input, produces an output. In your case 5.

This whole line will then look like this: `val constant5 : () => Int = () => 5`.

The part behind the `=` is the actual implementation. `() => 5` means no input, but return 5. `(x: Int) => x` would be a function which receives an Int and returns the given parameter (also called the identity function).

You can even nest them, e.g. `val fn: Int => Int => Int = x => y => x + y` would be a function, which receives a single Int and returns a new function, which expects another Int, when called returns the sum of both parameters. Calling this action would look like `fn(4)(5) // 9`. Hope this helps for your second task.